# Select from table under circumstances

Tags: sql, select

There is table with maker, model and type. I should select all makers that have more than 1 model, but all are the same type
my attempt is

```
select maker, type
from product
where 
((select count(model) from product) = (select count(model) from product where type='Printer')) or
((select count(model) from product) = (select count(model) from product where type='PC')) or
((select count(model) from product) = (select count(model) from product where type='Laptop'))
```

but it doesn't give correct answer. can anybody help me?

P.S. type can be only Printer, PC or Laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will probably get you the desired result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.maker, product.type
FROM product
INNER JOIN
(SELECT maker, count(distinct model) model_count, count(distinct type) type_count
FROM product
GROUP BY maker
HAVING count(distinct model) > 1
AND count(distinct type) = 1
) selected_makers
ON product.maker = selected_makers.maker
ORDER BY product.maker;
```

The inline view `selected_makers` first selects the makers that have more than one model but only one type. Then, the details for these makers are obtained from the `products` table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT maker 
FROM PRODUCT
GROUP BY type, maker
HAVING COUNT(model)>1;
```

Also, this is the sql fiddle file http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f09a/1

Answer (score 0):

Then I suppose this is what you want. Makers that have only 1 type, but multiple models:

```
SELECT maker FROM product
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
AND COUNT(DISTINCT type) == 1;
```

Comment: not exactly. this way if maker1 have models with types PC and Laptop it still will be selected. I need select only makers that have 1 type and many models

Comment: I think my edited answer now gives the desired result.